# In Python EVE how do I validate the where clause

Tags: python, eve

It seems that I can make GET requests to Eve and use a `?where` query where my filtering parameters are invalid (they do not pass the validation rules of my resource schema)

It seems that I can even post a `where` query with an attribute that doesn't even exist in the resource schema.

As of now, I get an empty list (of course, since there are no valid matches with these erroneous `where` filters) but is there a way to reject the request, outright, complaining about improper parameters or something...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Event hooks](http://eve.readthedocs.org/en/stable/features.html?highlight=hook#event-hooks)
In your specific case, you may need to use `pre_GET` hook.

In your hook function, you have access to the `request` object, where I think you can access the `where` clause.

You can raise `werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest` if your validation fails.

Comment: Well, I kinda knew that. :)  You can do almost anything you want with the provided hooks. I was hoping to have a switch turned on somehow and get it validated automatically, that maybe I missed or miseread. It's weird that no one asked for it, or not included by default!

Comment: Can you edit the question that you are looking for "builtin" validation or accept my answer ? ;)

Comment: I can see where you are coming from. I guess since there is no harm done (you get empty list, if incorrect query params) it wasn't an issue (yet?).


But I can imagine **builtin** validation of the query parameters being useful, especially if it returns useful error to the caller.